# FFT window corrupts signal

Tags: fft, distortion, window

this is a newbie question.
My goal is to create audio filter that cleans human speech from noise. I started with learning all about fft filters. At first I've created simple fft filter with rectangular window. But it was bad, I heard distortions in sound. So I decided to apply some window. I choose sinus window and now i hear noise because of window corrupts my signal.

My question is: what did i understood wrong about applying window? Should I perform some post-processing for result after ifft?

I wrote the code on python, you can make experiments with it. 
It can be executed this way:

```
python wfilter.py sample.wav > sample_filtered.wav
```

or, if wav file has more than one channel

```
python wfilter.py sample.wav -c 0 > sample_filtered.wav
```

My code (python):

```
import sys, re
import numpy as np
from scipy import fft, ifft, arange, fftpack
from scipy.io import wavfile
import math

rate, data = wavfile.read(sys.argv[1])
data_dtype = data.dtype
# duration in seconds
dur = len(data) / float(rate)

WINSIZE = 2048
BUFSIZE = WINSIZE * 3

def filter(data):    
    n = len(data) # length of the signal
    freqs = fftpack.fftfreq(n, d=(1.0 / rate)) 

    sig_fft = fft(data)

    sound = ifft(sig_fft).astype(data_dtype)
    return sound

def rect(buf):
    return buf

def sin(buf):
    N = len(buf)
    def fun(n):
        return math.sin(math.pi * n / N)          
    return buf * np.array([fun(x) for x in range(len(buf))] )

def wfilter(win = rect):
    result = None
    for left in xrange(0, len(data), WINSIZE):
        right = left + BUFSIZE
        buf = win(data[left:right])
        filter_buf = filter(buf)[:WINSIZE]
        if result is None:
            result = filter_buf
        else:
            result = np.concatenate([result, filter_buf])

    wavfile.write(sys.stdout, rate, result)


if __name__=='__main__':
    if "-c" in sys.argv:
        index = sys.argv.index("-c") + 1
        channel = int(sys.argv[index])
        chdata = np.array([x[channel] for x in data])
        data = chdata

    if hasattr(data[0], '__len__'):
        print "please specify channel, there are {} channels".format(len(data[0]))
        exit(1)

    wfilter(sin)
```

Comment: Where exactly did you read about those *FFT filters* which are simply zeroing-out values of spectra? This is highly incorrect. There are better methods and not very difficult, such as spectral subtraction, Wiener filtering, or even wonderful NMF.

Comment: ok, let modify my filter and remove any filtering in spectral scope. just fft and ifft. but distortions caused by window are still exists

Comment: That's another story. No need for windowing in frequency domain and definitely not in a such way. I don't really know from where you took this info, but this is definitely not a way to de-noise your speech.

Comment: I'm not doing windowing in frequency domain. I'm doing windowing in time domain. creating window in buffer, performing fft, then performing ifft, then writing to result array, then took next window, and repeating until end

Comment: I know - when you have your window applied it is obviously improving some aspects of spectra which is visible in frequency domain, but after performing the IDFT you still end up with windowed signal. That's not what you want. Obviously one might use complementary windows and correct overlap but it is still not a way to go. Speech denoising requires different methods.

Comment: so what should I do to not end up with windowed signal?  Should I apply (1/window) to result? I know, there are better algorithms to retrieve speech, but i want to know that I understand windowing correctly

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to apply a window too on the result of the ifft (`filter_buf` in your code). The reason is that there will be some point at which you will do transformations to your `sig_fft` variable - not merely reconstruct as is. This transformations might not preserve the property that the signal fades at the edges of its window, so what you get out of your `filter` function is not guaranteed to be properly windowed. Another way to look at it: you cannot simply cancel the effect of the window by dividing by "1/window" because whatever modification you will do in your `filter` function will not preserve the shape of the window.
2. Because of point 1., you need to have an overlap between your consecutive windows, otherwise the data on the edges of the windows will always be lost.
3. Because of point 2., to get perfect reconstruction, you need to chose a window function such that its square plus its square shifted by your overlap ratio equals one. Good start: overlap of 50% and sine window.

Of course, all this is needed if what you are doing with the fft data (`sig_fft`) cannot be done by other methods like classic FIR or IIR filters. If you plan to zero some coefficients to eliminate some frequencies, you're using the very wrong tool.